# ASP.NET MVC Debugging, updated libraries not used by IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

ASP.NET MVC, Visual Studio 2010, C#/.NET4.  I'm using IIS Express as the web server of choice, as it more accurately mirrors our production configurations in IIS7.  However, when I go through following process, the libraries used by IIS Express don't seem to be updating.

- Run app, find bug
- Stop VS2010, fix bug
- Build/Run
- Testing reveals the new code is not being used

IIS Express continues to run even after stopping the debugger in VS2010, so I'm assuming it's just holding onto the binaries that were used when it was initially launched.  Is there a way to get it to use the updated binaries?  Or is this the expected behavior?  Right now, the *only* way I can get the new binaries used is to completely exit VS2010 and then reload the project/solution.  Even selecting "stop" from the IISExpress systray icon doesn't seem to actually help (it doesn't appear to actually stop the process).

Obviously closing VS2010 and reloading the solution each time is a less-than-ideal workflow.

EDIT: The project is configured to run IIS Express from right click project -> Web.  The project URL does not use any virtual directories, it is at root of the local host on port 60830.  I thought I remembered seeing IIS Express in the F4 properties listing before, it's not listed there at all right now.

Comment: "as it more accurately mirrors our production configurations in IIS7"; what *practical* advantages does this give you?

Comment: @bzlm - is that relevant to Matt's question?

Comment: @Smudge202, why not? If it turns out they could just as well use the Visual Studio Web Server, then the problem is gone. :)

Comment: @Matt - to confirm, your web project/application in VS, you have changed the project's properties so that it runs in IIS Express under a given virtual directory?

Comment: @bzlm - one practical advantage I can think of, Cassini does not support TCP requests, necessary for certain WCF configurations. ^^  Another more relevant practical advantage would be SSL/TLS?  I'm sure they're are many but those are the only two I can think of

Comment: @Smudge202 I edited above, to answer your question